# In Australia, when a recruiter offers to talk to a company for you, would it give you better chances of landing the job?

Tags: australia

I am in touch with a recruiter and I appreciate his work. I was asked what other companies I have applied and I named one that I liked but have not listed themselves (as far as I know) as actively searching. If he offered to talk to them for me, would it give me better chances? Or should I leave the actively searching companies to recruiters and apply directly to the passive ones?

Comment: "I was asked what other companies I have applied and I named one that I liked" - did you already apply to that company (the one that's not advertising)? Did you receive a reply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, it will make no difference at all.

I am Australian and I use recruitment agents regularly.  However, if a job is advertised directly, then an agent will have no effect on your chances.  In fact, many companies who choose to advertise themselves specifically state on their job advertisements for "no agents".  This is to prevent them having to pay a commission to an agent.  If the company has *not* advertised any jobs, then there aren't any there and the agent talking on your behalf will *still* have no effect.

The reason the recruitment agent is offering to do this is to simply earn the commission for placing you in a role.  The best thing you can do is to keep going through [SEEK](http://www.seek.com.au) each day, look for job advertisements that you are qualified for and to apply.  Some will be advertised through agencies, some won't.  But cold calling companies, either directly or through an agency will not magically make a job appear.

Comment: Another Australian manager here - whenever we advertise directly, we ignore any calls from recruiters and simply direct them to the SEEK ad - so an agent offering to contact a company for an already advertised position will not get you anywhere at all. But re-reading the question shows that the OP hasn't yet applied to the company the recruiter is offering to talk to.

Answer (score 3):

I think approaching a company directly will likely give you more chance of landing the job. It shows that you would like to work for them and have taken the time to be proactive about applying. They will also avoid having to pay (the often hefty) recruitment fees!

A recruiter may be able to sell your skills to get you an interview but is unlikely to have too much influence on the end decision.

Answer (score 1):

Some famous individuals in my industry have described recruitment agencies as a "man in the middle attack" - in that their goals may be entirely unrelated to yours.

As an employer, I prefer to speak to individuals - partly because I know I will save 20 - 40% on hiring, but also because it shows a little initiative from the individual, and while I do have a few agencies retained, that is purely because they potentially have a wider pool of candidates than me.

But when I do use an agency - I expect them to be very strict and only pass me details for very strong candidates. Too many that don't fit, and the agency ends up not being on my supplier list any more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - I think some other answers have missed an important point in your question (they seem to be assuming you have already applied with the company in question):

> I named one that I liked but have not listed themselves (as far as I know) as actively searching

It may be that they have put a recruiter call out or he has a relationship with the company, so he may know there is a job there waiting or they might still interview you if he recommends you.

So, in this case, I would let the recruiter forward your details - it will have at least the same chance as you directly communicating with the organisation and, if he does have insider knowledge, would end up being a better chance.

Comment: You are correct, although in my example, it looks like said recruiter doesn't have any contact with them but plans to contact them in my behalf.

Comment: Yous should mention that in the question...